# Empty BasicBlock in LLVM

Tags: llvm

I have *.ll file, created by clang++ & llvm-dis. I have one simple question about **label:9** - it is empty, so is it useless? Can it be deleted without any negative effects, if I replace **br label %9** to **br label %10**? (Clang 3.1, Windows 7)

```
define void @_Z2f2v() nounwind {
  %a = alloca i32, align 4
  %b = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 2, i32* %a, align 4
  %1 = load i32* %a, align 4
  %2 = icmp sgt i32 %1, 0
  br i1 %2, label %3, label %4

; <label>:3                                       ; preds = %0
  store i32 555, i32* %b, align 4
  br label %10

; <label>:4                                       ; preds = %0
  %5 = load i32* %a, align 4
  %6 = icmp eq i32 %5, 111
  br i1 %6, label %7, label %8

; <label>:7                                       ; preds = %4
  store i32 999, i32* %b, align 4
  store i32 888, i32* %a, align 4
  br label %9

; <label>:8                                       ; preds = %4
  store i32 777, i32* %b, align 4
  br label %9

; <label>:9                                       ; preds = %8, %7
  br label %10

; <label>:10                                      ; preds = %9, %3
  ret void
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to get rid of `%9`, but you need to do so carefully:

- All branches to `%9` need to be replaced with branches to `%10`
- All phi instructions that reference `%9` need to be fixed to reference all of its predecessors instead. That's actually a legitimate reason for an empty basic block - to merge together multiple options for a succeeding phi.
- Remember that these are all really nameless basic blocks; if you do the modification on the textual IR itself (the .ll file), then removing `%9` will actually make `%10` the new `%9`. If you do the modification from LLVM itself, though (as you should), it doesn't matter.